# jquery pie chart with drilldown/clickable pie parts

Tags: jquery, pie-chart

I'm looking for a JQuery plugin to make pie charts whose wedges or slices I can click to go to another page based on the value of the pie wedge.

I'm having a pie chart with grades for a class (A-F). If someone clicks the "A" wedge, I want to redirect to a page that shows the A students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with jQuery and open flash charts

Answer (score 1):

[Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) has a pie plugin you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).  Its not a jQuery plugin, but it is js and can be used with jQuery as shown [here](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Charting-with-JavaScript.aspx).  The documentation is pretty sparse, but there are some good examples.  I think [this](http://g.raphaeljs.com/piechart2.html) one shows how to assign a link to each slice of the pie.