# Open source library for web-based drill down charts 

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have seen this [Good javascript library for drawing charts using json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227421/good-javascript-library-for-drawing-charts-using-json), which lists charting libraries. I thought to go for FLOT but I didnot see that it is supporting drill down bars.

Can any one suggest me whether FLOT supports them or any other library I can use? I am mainly looking for drill down bars and pie charts with support of javascript and jquery and can pull the chart data for these graphs.

There is Highcharts and JFreeChart, will that work? JFreeChart does not support drill down, though.

Comment: HighCharts are not commercially free.http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for open source. Can u suggest me once

Comment: @vishnu: what did you fins any good tool ??

Answer (score 29):

[d3.js](http://d3js.org/). See the gallery:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Drill down demos or examples:

- http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bar-hierarchy.html
- http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html
- http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html
- http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/
- http://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/
- http://thepowerrank.com/visual/NCAA_Tournament_Predictions
- http://square.github.com/crossfilter/
- http://windhistory.com/map.html#4.00/36.00/-95.00 / http://windhistory.com/station.html?KMKT
- http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/tru247/
- http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/metro-movers/
- http://marcinignac.com/projects/open-budget/viz/index.html
- http://bl.ocks.org/3630001
- http://bl.ocks.org/1346395
- http://bl.ocks.org/1314483
- http://slodge.com/teach/
- http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MultipleAreaChartsD3/
- http://bl.ocks.org/3287802

There are several tutorials. Here are two:

- http://www.12devsofxmas.co.uk/2012/01/data-visualisation/
- http://nickqizhu.github.com/dc.js/

And there are fiddle-like d3 editors:

http://www.d3-generator.com/

So to me, d3.js certainly seems like the best choice.

Comment: Thank you. I am not able to run and need more time to explore. i have less time to finish the task. Is there any easy thing to goahead

Comment: d3 treemap example at http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html is not actually drilldown its zoom. and fiddle like d3 editor is only good for bar chart.

Answer (score 2):

Go for http://kiersimmons.com/DDChart/index.html, it is a jquery plugin for drill down chart.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen DDChart. It only supports Drill down bar. Do we have any libray where it supports both? I think jqplot is not supporting drill down.

Comment: don't know any but these links may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963807/jquery-pie-chart-with-drilldown-clickable-pie-parts  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/pie-chart-jquery-ui-plugin