# Looking for a jQuery plugin to draw pie charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pie chart with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery)

I searched for a jQuery plugin which will help me to create pie charts and I found some which will help. But what I also want is to attach click function event handler for each sector of the pie chart.

Comment: Can you let us know what you've found so far, and what was not appropriate for your needs? This is useful since you may have missed a feature provided, and/or people won't want to suggest things you have already tried.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595834/open-source-library-for-web-based-drill-down-charts/12596951#12596951)

Comment: We are not google. Google is google

Comment: Plenty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery

Comment: They're also called *drill downs*, *drill-downs*, or *drilldowns*. if you didn't find many, that may have been why. There's a lot. [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) I think is the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## d3.js with NVD3.js:

---

http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html

Thing of beauty. And yes they have click features, including deep drills and reorientation, pivot and OLAP-style functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Farrish, can you please tell me how can I attach the click events. I couldn't find a proper document for that

Comment: [Here's a pie chart with the code to the right](http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav), there's a ton of code samples (on both the d3.js and NVD3 site), and the documentation is on the [d3.js site](http://d3js.org/).

Answer (score 7):

You should try Google charts. I have used that in one of my project, Google charts are easy to integrate and customizable. Try this

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: I am not supposed to send the data to third party :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's jqplot plugin http://www.jqplot.com/. It is free and can be modified easily to your needs, it has plenty of examples.

Comment: can I add click events for the sectors of the pie chart?

Comment: Yes I think so .. all you have to do is to check the examples to add littile bit code to the existing to get more functional;ity

Answer (score 0):

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

This is also completely HTML5, just throw it an HTML `table` and some options and then it'll turn it into a chart. You just need to include `type: 'pie'` in the `options`.

ALthough you don't get the interactivity you are after, sadly. It can be added though, using this improved version: https://github.com/irae/jquery-visualize

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely help you.

[Pie basic demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic)

You can download library file and sample code from here

[Highcharts download](http://www.highcharts.com/download)