# how to give chart as response in restful webservice

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, rest

My requirement is to collect the input data from user and send the chart as response.After research I found restful web service is the best way to do this.As per my requirement client does not know how to draw the chart based on the data.so I directly generate and return chart as response. but I can't send HTML as response in restful.rest response will be either text or XML or json.

How to return chart as response for URL request?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

In JAX-RS, you can return a image file with the help of  @Produces("image/image-type"). A sample code could be found here http://coenos.com/blog/?p=117

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to add a drill down chart?

Comment: For a drill down chart you can use any Javascript based UI framework like jQuery or AngularJS which are easily pluggable to any JAX-WS response as well. Pls check similar discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595834/open-source-library-for-web-based-drill-down-charts